# Java Random generate string from array preventing duplicates

Tags: arraylist, random

Sorry I am very new to java but I am having trouble finding a clear answer to fix the problem with my code. I am making a mad lib game that randomly generates nouns, adjectives, verbs, etc, and fills in the blanks in the story. I am finding that the code generates the same words over and over as I have multiple adjectives in the story. I am not sure how to fix this so there are no duplicates without having to change a lot of what I have already worked on. FYI I am aware my story doesn't have a spot for verbs yet. Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

     Scanner inputNouns = new Scanner(new File("nouns"));
    ArrayList<String> nouns = new ArrayList<>();
    while(inputNouns.hasNextLine())
        nouns.add(inputNouns.nextLine());
    Random rNouns = new Random();

    int randomNoun = rNouns.nextInt(nouns.size());
    String randomNounWord = nouns.get(randomNoun);

    Scanner inputVerbs = new Scanner(new File("verbs"));
    ArrayList<String> verbs = new ArrayList<>();
    while(inputVerbs.hasNextLine())
        verbs.add(inputVerbs.nextLine());
    Random rVerbs = new Random();

    int randomVerb = rVerbs.nextInt(verbs.size());
    String randomVerbWord = verbs.get(randomVerb);

    Scanner inputAdjectives = new Scanner(new File("adjectives"));
     ArrayList<String> adjectives = new ArrayList<>();
     while(inputAdjectives.hasNextLine())
        adjectives.add(inputAdjectives.nextLine());
     Random rAdjectives = new Random();

      int randomAdjective = rAdjectives.nextInt(adjectives.size());
    String randomAdjectiveWord = adjectives.get(randomAdjective);



     Scanner inputNames = new Scanner(new File("names"));
     ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
     while(inputNames.hasNextLine())
        names.add(inputNames.nextLine());
     Random rNames = new Random();

    int randomName = rNames.nextInt(names.size());
    String randomNameWord = names.get(randomName);

     Scanner inputPlaces = new Scanner(new File("places"));
     ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<>();
     while(inputPlaces.hasNextLine())
        places.add(inputPlaces.nextLine());
     Random rPlaces = new Random();

    int randomPlace = rPlaces.nextInt(places.size());
    String randomPlaceWord = places.get(randomPlace);




      System.out.println("Ladies and gentlemen, on this " + randomAdjectiveWord + " occasion");
       System.out.println("It is a privilege to address such a/an " + randomAdjectiveWord +" looking group of " +randomNounWord);
       System.out.println("I can tell from your smiling " +randomNounWord + " that you will support my");
       System.out.println(randomAdjectiveWord + " program in the coming election. I promise that, if elected,");
       System.out.println("there will be a/an " + randomNounWord + " in every " + randomNounWord+ ". I want to warn you aganist");
       System.out.println(randomAdjectiveWord + " opponent, " + randomNameWord +". They are nothing but a/an " +randomAdjectiveWord + " " +randomNounWord);
       System.out.println("They have a/an " +randomAdjectiveWord+ " character and is working "+randomNounWord+" in glove");
       System.out.println("with the criminal element. If elected for the offices of "+randomPlaceWord);
       System.out.println("I will eliminate the " +randomNounWord+ " off the streets. Thank you, and goodnight!");

    }
}
```

Comment: my assignment requirements: The Mad Lib should have a minimum of 15 empty spots to fill•For each empty spot, your program should pull a random word from an ArrayList.  •Each ArrayList should have a minimum of 15 entries to pick from. These entries should be read from an external file and placed in the ArrayList at runtime. You will have one external file for each category •Each spot should be filled with a randomly selected item from the appropriate list. If the word chosen was used in a previous spot, discard this word and pick another

Comment: Please add this comment to your question